# ¿Como asignar una imagen según la marca del equipo encontrado?

Tags: c#, android, xamarinforms

soy nueva en esto y estoy haciendo unas practicas sobre escanear una red local y mostrar detalles de información como su IP y que proveedor es....

Por ejemplo (Dell, HP, Cisco) pero me pidieron que mostrara el logo del proveedor en detalles junto con la IP y esa parte no se como hacerla, la aplicación es en Xamarin Forms.

el xaml es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RedMonIpScanner"
          x:Class="RedMonIpScanner.View.pruebaimagen">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,0,5">
        <Grid Margin="10,0,10,10" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Text="{local:Translate lblStatus}" TextColor="#000000" FontSize="Small" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <Frame BackgroundColor="{Binding ColorDevice}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Padding="5" Margin="20,3"></Frame>

            <Image Source="" />
            <Label Text="{local:Translate lblIpAddress}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Label Text="{Binding IP}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />

            <Label Text="{local:Translate lblProvider}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Provider}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Alguien me puede ayudar???

Comment: pero junto a los datos tienes el resource o link de la imagen que deberias mostrar? o la imagen de donde sale

Comment: Las imagenes lo tengo en resource, el nombre del proveedor me lo da una libreria que compara las mac de los equipos encontrados por medio del escaneo de IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes aplicar un `switch` usando `xaml`

```
<Image Width="48" Height="48">
  <Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Image">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding Provider}" Value="Dell">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/Dell.png"/>
            </DataTrigger >
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding Provider}" Value="HP">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/HP.png"/>
            </DataTrigger >
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Image.Style>
 </Image>
```

[Displaying an image based on value in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967416/displaying-an-image-based-on-value-in-xaml)

Comment: Me marca este error:

Position 32:34. The Property 'TargetType' is required to create a 'Xamarin.Forms.DataTrigger' object.

Comment: edite el codigo, habia puesto un ejemplo basado en wpf, creo que en Xamarin cambia un poco

Comment: Muchas gracias Leandro Tuttini